# Django:Setting up email

Tags: python, django, email

I created the following entries in my 'settings.py' file

```
# Email setup
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'someone@someorg.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'thepassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Then I issued the following command in the terminal:

```
email = EmailMessage('Hello','Have you received this mail?',to=['someone@gmail.com'])
```

I got `1` as an ouput.

When I checked the mailbox at 'someone@gmail.com',no mail was there in the mailbox.Did I miss something?

Comment: what hosting provider are you using? there needs to be some configuration on that end as well.

Comment: I'm just on the local machine,not using any host right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should setup `from_email` parameter (as a kwarg or 3rd arg) with `EmailMessage` call. Or define in settings.py:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'some.mail@inter.net'
```

This is taken as default if no `from_email` is provided to `EmailMessage`.

On a semi-related note, it's probably a good idea to also define `SERVER_EMAIL` in settings.py. This one is used with `mail_admins` and `mail_managers` by Django.

Answer (score 1):

All your settings are correct and complete, you just missed one thing at the end. You created a mail object and now `email` is ready to be sent email object, but you need to actually send it with `email.send()`. For more info and examples check Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/). Also, you can use `send_mail` which automatically creates the email object and sends it.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

mail_title = 'Hello!'
message = 'Have you received this mail?'
email = 'admin@company.com'
recipients = 'someone@gmail.com'

send_mail(mail_title, message, email, [recipients])
```

Comment: I sent the mail then only I got '1' as an output

Comment: Have you tried logging into the `'someone@someorg.com'` you set in `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and check the Sent Mail? Can you see it there? Or maybe an error mail that recipient is not available?

Answer (score 0):

According to the following link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/email/, you should put email in brackets. That means, it should look like this:

```
from django.core.mail.import send_mail

mail_title = 'Hello!'
message = 'Have you received this mail?'
email = admin@company.com
recipients = 'someone@gmail.com'

send_mail(mail_title, message, email, [recipients])
```